# Is there a default behavior that I can set to to tell my ships to cease fire when an enemy abandons their ship?

Tags: x4-foundations

I was just battling a pirate that had attacked one of my freighters. Happily, the pirate decided that they'd had enough and abandoned their lovely fighter. While I was sidling up to capture their ship, my freighter started shooting again. Fortunately, I was able to manually cancel all orders on the freighter and now I just have a lot of repair work to do.

Is there a default behavior setting for my ships that I can set that says "once an enemy has abandoned their ship, don't shoot it anymore"?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not. All you can is to tell them to cease fire by deleting the attack command, which might be too slow.